# How do I match non-letters before my token?

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, match

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I'm massively confused about why my RegEx isn't working.  I want to match a token from my array provided the stuff right before it is not letters.  My array is

```
2.4.0 :023 > GENDER_TOKENS
 => ["m", "male", "men", "f", "w", "female", "wom"]
```

So this should match

```
"2f 25"
```

as should

```
"f 100"
```

but not

```
"elf 25"
```

since the stuff before the "f" are not letters.  I thought this would do it ...

```
2.4.0 :021 > data = "elf 25"
 => "elf 25"
2.4.0 :022 >  Regexp.new("(^|[^\p{L}]+)#{Regexp.union(GENDER_TOKENS)}").match(data.downcase)
 => #<MatchData "elf" 1:"el">
```

But it's matching all the same.  Why sin't "^\p{L}]" matching non-letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the backslash before p is lost because of double quotes.

I don't know much ruby but I could check [here](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/393Vz8U1KD7E39vVL1jBViFaKVdJR0EpNzEnFUyn5oGoNBBRDmalwqTK83OVYq25Cooy80o0lDTiaqLjYgqqfWpjtTWVq4NS01MrCvRK8zLz8zRQ7NCsjclT0rTm@v8fAA).

Comment: `r = Regexp.new("(^|[^\\p{L}]+)#{Regexp.union(GENDER_TOKENS)}") #=> /(^|[^\p{L}]+)(?-mix:m|male|men|f|w|female|wom)/` fixes the problem you identified, but shortcomings remain (e.g, `"2 freaky 3".match?(r) #=> true`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland, i agree with your answer,

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you write your regex as follows.

```
r = /(?<!\p{L})#{Regexp.union(GENDER_TOKENS)}(?!\p{L})/
  #=> /(?<!\p{L})(?-mix:m|male|men|f|w|female|wom)(?!\p{L})/
```

which reads, "do not match a letter (negative lookbehind), match an element of `GENDER_TOKENS`, do not match a letter (negative lookahead)”.

```
"2f 25".match?(r)      #=> true
"2f25".match?(r)       #=> true
"2female".match?(r)    #=> true
"male 100".match?(r)   #=> true
"elf 25".match?(r)     #=> false
"2funky 25".match?(r)  #=> false
```

Note that the negative lookahead is needed. If we use the regex

```
rr = /(?<!\p{L})#{Regexp.union(GENDER_TOKENS)}/
  #=> /(?<!\p{L})(?-mix:m|male|men|f|w|female|wom)/
```

we can obtain erroneous results, such as

```
"2funky 25".match?(rr) #=> true
```

(because the token `"f"` is matched).